# Failed to deploy a sample Javascript HTTP adapter on MFP 8 (MobileFoundation Bluemix)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am beginning my journey into the MobileFirst Platform 8 Beta, and I would like to deploy my very first sample adapter.
I am using an instance of the Mobile Foundation service on Bluemix.

When trying to deploy the sample adapter, I get the error stack below:

> ○ → mvn adapter:deploy -e
>   [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building SampleAdapter 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.0:deploy (default-cli) @ SampleAdapter ---
>   [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 1.845 s
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-13T15:50:57+02:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/299M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project SampleAdapter: Unexpected response from http://mobilefoundation-test-server.mybluemix.net/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters: -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project SampleAdapter: Unexpected response from http://mobilefoundation-test-server.mybluemix.net/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters:
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       
> at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unexpected response from http://mobilefoundation-test-server.mybluemix.net/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters:
>   
>       
> at com.ibm.mfp.adapter.plugin.MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.handleDeployResponse(MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.java:206)
>       
> at com.ibm.mfp.adapter.plugin.MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.deploy(MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.java:119)
>       
> at com.ibm.mfp.adapter.plugin.MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.execute(MfpMavenAdapterPluginDeploy.java:108)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       ... 20 more
>   
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Could someone please provide some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not really failed deployment. This is a known issue that is resolved internally.

Visit your console and you will see that the adapter is there, deployed.
Alternatives:

- Use the MobileFirst CLI (v8.0 beta) to deploy the adapter file
- Deploy the .adapter file manually in the console