# MobileFirst 8.0 GA - HTTP JS adapter deploy failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters, ibm-mobile-services

When I try to deploy a simple JS HTTP adapter to Bluemix MFP8 I am getting the following error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.0:deploy (default-cli) on project
>   TestAdapter: Unexpected response from
>   http://nnnnnnnnn-server.mybluemix.net:80/mfpadmin/management-apis/2.0/runtimes/mfp/adapters:
>   -> [Help 1]

Though I get the error message, the adapter is deployed and works fine. However, the error looks really bad and I cannot go do a customer POC.

I saw a post on this issue in stackoverflow.com [Failed to deploy a sample Javascript HTTP adapter on MFP 8 (MobileFoundation Bluemix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212283/failed-to-deploy-a-sample-javascript-http-adapter-on-mfp-8-mobilefoundation-blu) for MFP8 beta and the answer was it is a known issue and resolved internally.

Even in MFP8 GA, this issue is not resolved. Any plans to fix this?

PS:  When I deploy the same to the local MFP8 server, I do not see this message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1. Update to the latest CLI build: `npm update -g mfpdev-cli` and make sure using `mfpdev -v` that your version is "8.0.0-2016070716"
2. Delete the .m2 folder, in Mac it is located at the root folder: "~/.m2"

Now you can create a new adapter, build and deploy it to either local servers or remote servers.

Comment: Followed the instructions everything working fine now.
PS: You have to create a new adapter. If you try to deploy an existing adapter after the above change, still will get the same error message.

Thank you.